# Java's String .replaceFirst is not working and I don't know if its a bug or I did it wrong

Tags: java, string, replace

Ok I have a method that is replacing text when I use string.replace() it works but when I switch to relpaceFirst() as shown below it no longer works, what am I doing wrong or missing here?

```
private void acceptAccButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
    int selectedAcTableItem = validAcTable.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedSugTableItem = suggestedAcTable.getSelectedRow();
    if (selectedAcTableItem > 0) {
        String acNameDefthmlText = htmlText;
        String parensName = "";
        String acName = validAcTable.getValueAt(selectedAcTableItem, 0).toString();
        String acDef = validAcTable.getValueAt(selectedAcTableItem, 1).toString();
        String acSent = validAcTable.getValueAt(selectedAcTableItem, 2).toString();
        StringBuilder acBuilder = new StringBuilder(acDef);
        acBuilder.append(" (").append(acName).append(")");            
        if (!acDef.equals("")) {
            parensName = " (" + acName + ")";
            if (htmlText.contains(acName) && !htmlText.contains(acBuilder)){
                String acReplace = acBuilder.toString();
                String acOrigDefName = acDefRow + parensName;
                if (htmlText.contains(acOrigDefName) && parensName.contains(acOrigName)){
                    acNameDefthmlText = htmlText.replaceFirst(acOrigDefName, acReplace);
                } else if (htmlText.contains(acName)) {
                    acNameDefthmlText = htmlText.replaceFirst(acName, acReplace);
                }
                htmlText = acNameDefthmlText;

            }                
            validAcTable.setValueAt(true, selectedAcTableItem, 2);
            Acronym acronym = createNewAcronym(acName, acSent, acDef, true);
            try {

                AcronymDefinitionController.sharedInstance().writeAcronymToExcelSheet(acName, acDef);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }
            if (validAcTable.getRowCount() - 1 >= validAcTable.getSelectedRow() + 1) {
                validAcTable.changeSelection(selectedAcTableItem + 1, 0, true, true);
            }
            validAcTable.repaint();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your input, what output are you getting, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you give an example for it, to state in what case it is not working aprt from the code? Also, if you have somehow, an `empty` string as first argument, in `replaceFirst`, it will betray you and work in the way you didn't think of.

Comment: just limit your code to what is not working, and if possible, write it like a unit test with actual data rather than the variables.

Comment: It is unlikely you caught a bug, it is your data playing the tricks with you.

Comment: Remember that the input params to String.replaceFirst(string, string) are regular expressions not just literal strings, so values in strings that have special meaning in the Regex implementation may not evaluate correctly. here is teh javadoc for class String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 . "Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired. "

Comment: @FrankThomas That's not entirely accurate. One parameter will be a regular expression and has to be quoted with `Pattern.quote()` the other will be a related, but completely different type of expression that can contain placeholders for the capture groups, and has to be quoted with `Matcher.quoteReplacement()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice the signature of two methods in question:

```
replace(char oldChar,char newChar);
replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement);

replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement);
```

As you can see, in `replaceFirst` you matching argument is treated as `regex`(regular expression), which will cause the difference if any special chars are involved in the argument.

For example: consider below:

```
System.out.println("abcdab".replace("ab", "ef"));  //<- replaces all
System.out.println("abcdab".replaceFirst("ab", "ef"));//<-replaces first
System.out.println("\\abcdab".replace("\\ab", "ef")); //<-replaces first
System.out.println("\\abcdab".replaceFirst("\\ab", "ef"));
//^ doesn't replace as `\` is an special char
```

Comment: That fixed the issue when I replaced the string with the regular expression it worked like a charm.